# Does the newest Nvidia driver support 3D Vision in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii, technical-issues

I used version 300+

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/3123040038?page=2 says that version 280+ already support diablo 3.

Yet when I tried diablo 3 in 3D I do not see anything different. It still look 3D but as any 3D run on full screen.

It's  not impressive. What am I missing? Do I need to set up a 3D profile for diablo 3? If so how?

Some said that diablo 3 is simply not 3D ready yet.

In general any video card have data on the depth. So I wonder why the game has to be 3D ready? As long as they display 3D rendered images any video card should be able to incorporate that.

Comment: Have you also enabled Stereoscopic 3D in the Nvidia Control Panel?

Comment: There's a difference between a first person shooter, where depth is part of the calculations, and a third person isometric view, where most things are a constant distance away.

Comment: Yes of course I have enabled stereoscopic 3d. I just need to test my 3D glasses with something.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can play Diablo 3 in Stereoscopic 3D. Here is a great guide in setting it up: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5960916051

Answer (score 1):

[418 was the last driver to support 3D vision for all games.](https://www.engadget.com/2019/03/11/nvidia-ends-3d-vision-support/)

- [Official Link](https://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/418.91/418.91-desktop-win10-64bit-international-whql.exe)
- [Mirror](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8bpq586srqi4ft0/418.91-desktop-win10-64bit-international-whql.exe?dl=0)